# Переход по кнопке из одного активити во фрагмент другого активити. Как реализовать?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть два активити. В первом активити есть fragment1 и fragment2. В fragment1 есть кнопка, запускающая второе активити, а в нем есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должно открываться fragment2 из первого активити. Как надо написать onClick кнопки во втором активити, чтобы открылся fragment2 из первого?

Comment: с интентом запуска активити передавайте параметр - какой именно фрагмент надо открывать (например передавайте true для второго, если их всего два, это несколько упростит логику ветвления или число, если вариантов больше) или, если у вас возврат по иерархии (текущее активити закрывается `finsh()`), то это же значение передавайте интентом через `onActivityResult()`